# Smooth but non-analytic kernel functions

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, differential-topology

Does there exist a (stationary) covariance kernel function which is $C^\infty$-smooth but not real analytic? If so, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 5):

With $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+}$, $t,x$ real,
$
H(t)t^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/t}
$
is the fundamental solution of the heat equation, $C^\infty$ everywhere except at $(0,0)$, analytic only outside $t=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Take a schwarz class function f  with compact support.  It won't be real analytic for that  reason at least.$g =  f(x)*f(-x)$ is the fourier transform of the non-negative function $|\hat f|^2$, and  it is smooth with compact support.  By Bochner's thm it is a co-variance kernel.